# Understanding an asbestos test report?

Tags: asbestos

My elderly mother had the insulation in her attic tested and we are having difficulty understanding the report.  The company that suggested the test says its bad but we are not sure if they are just looking to make money from her (which she does not have)?
[image: asbestos report]

Comment: Not an expert by any means - it appears that two suspicious substances were tested (phase A and B).  In phase A, no asbestos is present (noted in the comments).  Phase B is estimated to be >75% asbestos, 0.5-5% cellulose, and the remainder non-fibrous.

Comment: Chrysotile is asbestos. However *"Asbestos is only a danger if it becomes airborne. Sometimes the best solution is to leave the insulation in place, and take steps to protect your home against any airborne asbestos particles."*